# e-commerce site - handling basket quantity

Tags: php

I'm currently building a basic e-commerce site. The process is as follows:

```
View Basket -> Address Details -> Payment -> Thank you
```

The site will be using sessions to store basket data - a typical `print_r()` of `$_SESSION['products']` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [19] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 2
            [line_total] => 20
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 2
            [line_total] => 50
        )
)
```

The numerical indexes of this array is the unique product ID. My questions are as follows:

1) Suppose a user was to a add a quantity of a particular product to their basket. Then they leave the screen as it is for a period of time. When they come back they press "continue" - however during this time the product stock has decreased and their requested quantity is not available. What should happen at this point?

2) The above scenario may also occur at the point just before taking payment. What would be the best way to handle this without doing stuff that the customer will not be expecting?

Note, I don't plan to build a "reserve" functionality for this system.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Study concurrent programming

Comment: something wrong with all the existing -ecommerce site you can use for free?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue before creating my own system. The answer is dependent on what you want to do.

My logic:

- At anytime you are showing the shopping cart you should do an inventory check, if it isn't in stock the item(s) should be removed with a message notifying the customer.
- If during the payment completion the item is suddenly not in stock you should do the same as above and do not proceed with payment.

Answer (score 1):

You must always check not only the product existence at the checkout, but also the price, which also could change.

Do the same also every time the user reenters the page.

Besides that, you could also develop a function that runs every certain time to check that in the case the user takes too long in the page.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell your process should be more like this:

**View Basket** -> Check Inventory -> Pass? keep going. Fail? send back to View Basket with notification message -> **Address Details** -> Check Inventory -> Pass? keep going. Fail? send back to View Basket with notification message -> **Payment** -> Check Inventory -> Pass? keep going. Fail? send back to View Basket with notification message -> Inventory Passed: -1 inventory -> Attempt Payment -> Pass? Cool. Fail? +1 inventory, send back to View Basket with notification message -> **Thank you**